# Align the text/picture within a tile

Tags: html, css

On left side you see my current state, on the right side I have used a image-editing programm to show how I want that the tiles looks like. I have tried a bit, but every time when I tried to add for example the "xxx" text, the whole tile has been moved up. I would appreciate it, when someone could solve it for me.

[image]

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
.main .inner {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0px;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.main .inner:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #2e8bcc;
}
.tile h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-align: center;
}
.tile {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  border: 5px solid #AAAAAA;
  opacity: 8;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  display: inline-block;
}
.body {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 4</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 5</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 6</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 6</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 7</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should add .tile img{margin-left:15px;} to center it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code. I've only added

```
.tile {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
.main .inner {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0px;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.main .inner:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #2e8bcc;
}
.tile h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-align: center;
}
.tile {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  border: 5px solid #AAAAAA;
  opacity: 8;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.body {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 1</h2>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>xxxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 2</h2>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>xxxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 3</h2>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>xxxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 4</h2>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>xxxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 5</h2>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>xxxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 6</h2>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>xxxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 6</h2>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>xxxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 7</h2>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>xxxxx</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is when for example a name or the text "xxx" is missed on 1 tile, the tile are moved up. I want that they have the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float:left` to `.tile` div and it will work fine

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
.main .inner {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0px;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.main .inner:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #2e8bcc;
}
.tile h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-align: center;
}
.tile {
  float:left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  border: 5px solid #AAAAAA;
  opacity: 8;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  display: inline-block;
}
.body {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 1</h2>
      <h4>xxxxxx</h> 
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 4</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 5</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 6</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 6</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>Name 7</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```